# Null Space Of A Matrix,How it is Related to that of The Null Space of The Matrix Representing The Linear Transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

We all Know That Linear Transformation from one vector Space To another can be represented by a unique Matrix w.r.t two specific bases of the given vector spaces.

1. Null Space of a  Matrix A over a vector space V is {x belonging to V: Ax=0}
2. Null Space of a linear Transformation L:V->W is 
     {v belonging to V: L(v)=0}

I want to know the following!

1. How can we relate the above two concepts ?
2. I really cannot figure out  How basis is coming into play when we are relating 1 & 2.
3. Is the Linear Transformation Matrix A is the same Matrix we are talking about in the NULL space of that Matrix?

Please Help me starting from how the Actual matrix representing the Linear Transformation is related to its NULL Space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\newcommand {\bv}{{\mathbf v}}
\newcommand {\bb}{{\mathbf b}}
$$
A vector $\bv$ in the nullspace of $L$ is an element of $V$.

If $A$ is the matrix of $L$ with respect to the basis $B = \{\bb_1, ..., \bb_n\}$, and if $\bv$, in this basis, can be written

$$
v = a_1 \bb_1 + a_2 \bb_2 + \ldots + a_n \bb_n
$$
where the $a$s are scalars, then the coordinate vector $\bv' = \begin{bmatrix} a_1\\a_2\\\ldots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix}$ will  be in the nullspace of the matrix $A$.

Comment: thanks !! Is it true when B is the Canonical Base or always?

Comment: Ok I got it !  We will then multiply with the basis change matrix.thank you!!